# Can you put out an oil well fire in Tekkit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

Wanting to go to space I started my base next to some oil wells. Today when I logged on to my server, I was welcomed by this view:

[image: Oil wells on fire]

... what are my options here? Can I put them out somehow? What do I do?

Comment: well then. You could try going into the server options and disabling firespread, but I don't think that will extinguish it. Rain might help

Comment: Disabling firespread doesn't stop it, but does help when trying to put it out. Rain does nothing :/ Seems I might have to drop water on top of every spot, which will take forever... Maybe I'll just have to start pumping it up and see if I can save it that way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a friend of mine had the same problem, and it wasnt a problem in the end, they just pumped it up like normal no biggy.

Comment: they do kind of make good beacons for sea travels...

Answer (score 2):

Managed to put it out doing the following:

- `/gamemode doFireTick false`
- Cover the layer *above* the oil with dirt to put out the fire (including the 5 blocks at the top of the oil thing
- `/gamemode doFireTIck true`

Answer (score 2):

There is a much better solution: go to the buildcraft config (usually tekkitfolder/config/buildcraft/main.conf), and then find the line:

```
B:burnOil=true
```

And simply set it to false. This will disable burning oil completely, without messing with other fire behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the oil fires do waste the oil, let it burn long enough (couple of hours, sometimes a few days..., that is real time, not in game...) and the fire will clean all the oil...
Had this storage tank, figured dumping oil in there with flood gates was a cheaper option than building a shitload of tanks, and after a weeks vacation come to see it on fire and about empty....